# Gitlab CI / Получить только apk

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

При сборке проекта можно скачать архив, но apk лежит в:

```
Artifact/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/
```

Как можно получать сразу apk?

Мой файл  **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Read more about this script on this blog post https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/, by Greyson Parrelli
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "25"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "24.0.0"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "24.4.1"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.tgz https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.tgz
  - tar --extract --gzip --file=android-sdk.tgz
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/ && cp sdk-licenses/* $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```

Строкой - app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk я получаю zip архив с единственным файлом app-debug.apk. Но мне нужно только apk без /app/build/outputs/apk/debug/ можно в архиве или только apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете просто скопировать его - описав скрипт с копированием.
В вашем случае так например:

```
script: ./gradlew assembleDebug; mv app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk [ожидаемое_расположение]
```

, где [ожидаемое_расположение] - тот путь где вы хотите сохранить app-debug.apk после сборки.

Comment: Возможно поможет.